# How to simplify boolean function into two logic gates?

Tags: boolean, logic, simplify

Can anyone help me to simplify this boolean function into two logic gates?

```
C(out) = AC(in) + BC(in) + AB
```

Comment: What kind of gates exactly ? Can they have more than two inputs ? Are XOR gates allowed ?

Comment: Are 3-input gates allowed or must they only be 2-input ?

Comment: "Using only two-input logic gates (AND, OR, XOR) and inverters (NOT), design a circuit that takes A, B, and Cin as its inputs and produces the Cout output. Try to use the fewest number of gates possible."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression represents what is commonly known as a three input [majority gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority_function#Boolean_circuits) - the output is TRUE only when the majority of inputs are true (2 or 3 inputs must be true for the 3 input case). In general it takes 4 basic logic gates to implement this (5 if you you are restricted to 2-input gates).

If you Google for "majority gate" you will find a variety of implementations, e.g. on [this page](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~dj/cs3843/lecture2.html) I found the following, which I think matches your criteria (other than the unfeasible requirement of doing it with only 2 gates):

[image]

Comment: "Using only two-input logic gates (AND, OR, XOR) and inverters (NOT), design a circuit that takes A, B, and Cin as its inputs and produces the Cout output. Try to use the fewest number of gates possible."

Answer (score 0):

About majority function with n boolean variables. 
for n variables, f(x1,x2,...xn) there will be total nC[n/2] terms for OR operation. Each term contains [n/2] variables for AND operation.

ex: f(00111)= OR{ and(0,0,1) and(0,0,1) and(0,0,1) and(0,1,1)  and(,0,1,1) and(0,1,1,) and(0,1,1) and (0,1,1,) and(0,1,1,) and(1,1,1 )

=0 OR 0 OR 0 OR...... OR 1=1=majority of ones is true.